# Beginners' guide to publications in mathematics

Tags: publications, mathematics

I solved an interesting problem in probability, and I think it's worth publishing as an interesting application. However, I am not a mathematician and don't know anything about existing journals or conferences where my problem may fit.

Is there a comprehensive guide with all the important journals and conferences in math, with an explanation of what kind of papers they may publish?

Comment: For a start, you may look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scientific_journals_in_mathematics

Comment: A more formal list can be found at http://www.ams.org/msnhtml/serials.pdf and a list with links is at http://www.mathontheweb.org/mathweb/mi-journals5.html

Comment: I notice that you are a computer scientist. Many mathematics problems can be published at venues devoted to computer science, depending on the problem. Perhaps if you gave a few keywords describing the area, people might be able to direct you to something useful. _Mathematics is a huge subject with hundreds of journals._ No one is going to list them all here.

Comment: Your university has a strong mathematics department.  Have you talked to any of your local math faculty?  Also, the default advice for where to publish anything applies here: Consider the journal(s) that you cite most often!

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the literature related to your problem, it may well be that the solution has already been published.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention that you are not a mathematician and that you feel that your solution to a math problem is worth publishing.  If you are an undergraduate, you might want to consider journals targeted at authors who are undergraduates (search the internet for "undergraduate math journal").

If you are not an undergraduate (or even if you are), I recommend you look at the three journals published by the [Mathematics Association of America](http://www.maa.org/subpage_2.html):

- [Mathematics Magazine](http://www.maa.org/pubs/mathmag.html) "offers lively, readable, and appealing exposition on a wide range of mathematical topics."  (Read more about it [here](http://www.maa.org/pubs/mm-guide.html).)
- [The College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/pubs/cmj.html) "is designed to enhance classroom learning and stimulate thinking regarding undergraduate mathematics. It publishes articles, short Classroom Capsules, problems, solutions, media reviews and other pieces. All are aimed at the college mathematics curriculum with emphasis on topics taught in the first two years."  (Read more about it [here](http://www.maa.org/pubs/cmj_info.html).)
- [The American Mathematical Monthly](http://www.maa.org/pubs/monthly.html) "publishes articles, notes, and other features about mathematics and the profession. Its readers span a broad spectrum of mathematical interests and abilities. Authors are invited to submit articles and notes that bring interesting mathematical ideas to a wide audience of Monthly readers."

Comment: I posted this answer before I discovered that the original poster (OP) was in the field of computer science.  I agree with Dave Clarke's comment above.  If the result that the OP obtained is more on the theoretical computer science side, then perhaps my suggestions above are not appropriate.

Comment: Actually, Math Magazine and College Mathematics Journal are basically 100% expository, so they are not the place to send original research.  The Monthly covers a broader range of the spectrum between exposition to research, but it aims for papers that are very accessible and interesting to a broad audience.  Most specialized research is not, and in fact the Monthly rejects well over 90% of submissions.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician, I agree with you.  I had assumed that the OP was an amateur, hence my recommendation above.  It seems my assumption was wrong.  I will return 12 hours from now.  If the OP provides more info, then I can edit my answer; otherwise, I will delete it.

Comment: Joel Reyes Noche, I am a computer scientist, but the problem I am interested in has no relation to computer science - it resulted from a study of a subject related to Biblical economy - land division and Jubilee. One of the models I thought of resulted in an interesting probabilistic problem. This is not really a new research - only an interesting application.

Comment: @Erel: since the fact that "This is not really a new research - only an interesting application" may affect materially the answer you will receive, may I suggest you edit that into your question statement above?

Comment: @Eral: If it's "not really new research", then it's not publishable in most mathematics journals.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi, thank you for your response.  I will keep my answer as is, as I think the publications I mentioned might be relevant.