# Math journal for young mathematicians

Tags: journals, mathematics

I think I have good results for publishing a paper in a math journal, but I've never published one. I need a propose about any good math journal in mathematics for young mathematicians who have never published a paper. It can be with impact factor or with international board.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are a few journals aimed at work by undergraduate students, but beyond that I don't know of any journals that specifically solicit work from young mathematicians. Most mathematicians publish their first papers in the same journals as   their fiftieth.

Comment: May be I didn't described good my question! I mean about normal journals, but since I've never published a paper, I've heard that it is hard to infiltrate in these journals.

Comment: I would ask your professors for suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

If you're a student you should consider Involve, or other publications geared toward student authors.

Answer (score 5):

If you are a high school student or an undergraduate, then you might want to read the answers to [Journals for undergraduates](https://mathoverflow.net/q/36850/12357), [Math journal for high school students?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/7329/12357), and [What are some examples of journals that will accept undergraduate student research?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/49197/12357).

Comment: You might also want to look at [Beginners' guide to publications in mathematics](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1439/64).